# Not able to store info in CSV (Python Webscraping)

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My code does not store the result correctly into the csv file that I have created.

I need to pull data on the number, sponsor, and party for every bill from the [U.S. Congress website](https://www.congress.gov/search?q=%7B%22source%22%3A%22legislation%22%2C%22congress%22%3A%22115%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22bills%22%7D&page=).

When running the code in the interpreter, it works correctly and gives me the results I want. However, in the csv file that I create I have one of the following issues:

- the same Sponsor-Party **for every bill** (correct bill number, but all of them sharing the same Sponsor-Party)

```
SPONS  PARTY NBILL
Name   D     7402
Name   D     7401
...
```

Interestingly, the name that I found (Grijalva, Raul) corresponds to Bill 7302.

- The correct Sponsor-Party, but just the 100-th bill, namely each 100 Sponsor-Party I have 7402;7302 and so on.

As above, different Sponsors and Party, but the numbers of bills changes just every 100 Sponsor/Party pair and goes 100 by 100 (7402 for the first 100 pair, 7302 for the second and so on)

- Correct Sponsor-Party **but no bills**, which is what happens with the following code

**EDIT:** If I put the `Congress=[-]+[-]+[-]` at the end of the code I fell in the first case named.

```
 with open('115congress.csv', 'w') as f:
        fwriter=csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
        fwriter.writerow(['SPONS', 'PARTY', 'NBILL'])
        BillN=[]
        Spons=[]
        Party=[]
        for j in range(1, 114):
            hrurl='https://www.congress.gov/search?q=%7B%22source%22%3A%22legislation%22%2C%22congress%22%3A%22115%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22bills%22%7D&page='+str(j)
            hrpage=requests.get(hrurl, headers=headers)
            data=hrpage.text
            soup=BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
            for q in soup.findAll('span', {'class':'result-item'}):
                for a in q.findAll('a', href=True, text=True, target='_blank'):
                    secondindex=secondindex+1
                    if (secondindex/2).is_integer():
                        continue
                    Spons=a.text
                    print(Spons)
                    SPONS=Spons
                    if 'R' in Spons:
                        Party='Republican'
                    if 'D' in Spons:
                        Party='Democratic'
                    print(Party)
                    PARTY=Party
                    Congress115=[SPONS]+[PARTY]
                    fwriter.writerow(Congress115)
            for r in soup.findAll('span', {'class':'result-heading'}):
                index=index+1
                if (index/2).is_integer():
                    continue
                Bill=r.findNext('a')
                BillN=Bill.text
                print(BillN)
                NBILL=BillN
                Congress115= [SPONS]+[PARTY]+[NBILL]
                fwriter.writerow(Congress115)

    f.close()
```

How can I fix my code that writes to the CSV so that I do not have these issues?

Comment: Are you sure about writing `Congress115` variable to the csv file twice? Once with `Congress115=[SPONS]+[PARTY]` and the other time with `Congress115= [SPONS]+[PARTY]+[NBILL]`. And even the indentation of your code feels a bit off at `for r in soup.findAll('span', {'class':'result-heading'}):`. Given the work that your code does, I strongly feel that this loop and it's contents should have been a part of the `for q in soup.findAll('span', {'class':'result-item'}):` loop.

Comment: If I understand correctly u are suggesting to put Congress115=[-]+[-]+[-] AT THE END of the code and to include the for r loop in the previous one? I'll try, thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to show what a few lines of the output CSV file should look like?  i.e. your expected output

Answer (score 1):

I did not understand all of the questions you had regarding your code, because I wasn't able to reproduce your errors. However, I think there are several problems with your code and I'd like to show you another possible approach.

I think one of your main mistakes is to write the variables multiple times to your csv-file. Moreover, you will get a lot of false entries regarding the party if you only look for a single character within a string that contains the party abbrev as well as a name.

Assuming you want to extract the `bill_nr`, `spons` and the `party` from every entry, you could do the following (see the comments within the code):

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for j in range(1,114):
  hrurl=f'https://www.congress.gov/search?q=%7B%22source%22%3A%22legislation%22%2C%22congress%22%3A%22115%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22bills%22%7D&page={j}'
  hrpage=requests.get(hrurl)
  data=hrpage.text
  soup=BeautifulSoup(data, 'html5lib')

  # get the main div, that contains all entries on the page
  main_div = soup.find('div', {'id':'main'})
  # every entry is within a <li> element
  all_li = main_div.findAll('li', {'class':'expanded'})

  # iterate over <li>-elements
  for li in all_li:
    # get BILL_NR
    bill_nr_raw = li.find('span', {'class':'result-heading'}).text
    # I assume only the first part is the Nr, so you could extract it with the following
    bill_nr = bill_nr_raw.split()[0]
    # get SPONS
    spons_raw = li.find('span', {'class':'result-item'})
    spons = spons_raw.find('a').text

    # get PARTY
    # check if the string starts with one of the following to ensure you pick the right party
    if spons.startswith('Rep'):
      party = 'Republican'
    elif spons.startswith('Dem'):
      party = 'Democratic'

    # put all the information you extracted from this single entry (=<li>-element) into a list and write that list (=one row) to the csv file
    entry = [bill_nr, spons, party]
    with open('output.csv', 'a') as out_file:
      out = csv.writer(out_file)
      out.writerow(entry)
```

Note that the use of f-strings (at the beginning of the main loop) is only supported in Python >3.6.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is really usefull. Love to see diffent way to do the same thing, really get into the program. The only think that I m not able to do with this code, and I m trying, is to have each "entry", namely bill_nr, spons, party, into a separate column.

Comment: I ran the code and it outputs every entry into a separate row. Mind the indentation and watch out that the part where you write the entry to your csv (starting with `with open('output.csv', 'a') as out_file:` is within the `for` loop.

Comment: The problem is that I need a column for each variable, a column full of the numbers of bill, one full of sponsors and one full of parties. I'll try to figure out how to store it in this way, after all I have to do something. Thank you so much for your help and your time

Answer (score 1):

A better approach would be to loop over a different element e.g. `<li>` and then find the required elements inside that.

To get the cosponsors, you first need to test if there are any by checking the number. If this is not `0` then first obtain the link to the subpage. Request this sub page using a separate BeautifulSoup object. The table containing the cosponsors can then be parsed and all of the cosponsors added to a list. You could add extra processing here if needed. The list is then combined into a single string to allow it to be saved to a single column in the CSV file.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import requests
import string

headers = None

with open('115congress.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    fwriter = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
    fwriter.writerow(['SPONS', 'PARTY', 'NBILL', 'TITLE', 'COSPONSORS'])

    for j in range(1, 3):  #114):
        print(f'Getting page {j}')

        hrurl = 'https://www.congress.gov/search?q=%7B%22source%22%3A%22legislation%22%2C%22congress%22%3A%22115%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22bills%22%7D&page='+str(j)
        hrpage = requests.get(hrurl, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(hrpage.content, 'lxml')

        for li in soup.find_all('li', class_='expanded'):
            bill_or_law = li.span.text
            sponsor = li.find('span', class_='result-item').a.text
            title = li.find('span', class_='result-title').text
            nbill = li.find('a').text.strip(string.ascii_uppercase + ' .')

            if '[R' in sponsor:
                party = 'Republican'
            elif '[D' in sponsor:
                party = 'Democratic'
            else:
                party = 'Unknown'

            # Any cosponsors?
            cosponsor_link = li.find_all('a')[2]

            if cosponsor_link.text == '0':
                cosponsors = "No cosponsors"
            else:
                print(f'Getting cosponsors for {sponsor}')
                # Get the subpage containing the cosponsors
                hr_cosponsors = requests.get(cosponsor_link['href'], headers=headers)
                soup_cosponsors = BeautifulSoup(hr_cosponsors.content, 'lxml')
                table = soup_cosponsors.find('table', class_="item_table")

                # Create a list of the cosponsors
                cosponsor_list = []

                for tr in table.tbody.find_all('tr'):
                    cosponsor_list.append(tr.td.a.text)

                # Join them together into a single string
                cosponsors = ' - '.join(cosponsor_list)

            fwriter.writerow([sponsor, party, nbill, f'{bill_or_law} - {title}', cosponsors])
```

Giving you an output CSV file starting:

```
SPONS;PARTY;NBILL;TITLE;COSPONSORS
Rep. Ellison, Keith [D-MN-5];Democratic;7401;BILL - Strengthening Refugee Resettlement Act;No cosponsors
Rep. Wild, Susan [D-PA-15];Democratic;7400;BILL - Making continuing appropriations for the Coast Guard.;No cosponsors
Rep. Scanlon, Mary Gay [D-PA-7];Democratic;7399;BILL - Inaugural Fund Integrity Act;No cosponsors
Rep. Foster, Bill [D-IL-11];Democratic;7398;BILL - SPA Act;No cosponsors
Rep. Hoyer, Steny H. [D-MD-5];Democratic;7397;BILL - To provide further additional continuing appropriations for fiscal year 2019, and for other purposes.;No cosponsors
Rep. Torres, Norma J. [D-CA-35];Democratic;7396;BILL - Border Security and Child Safety Act;Rep. Vargas, Juan [D-CA-51]* - Rep. McGovern, James P. [D-MA-2]*
Rep. Meadows, Mark [R-NC-11];Republican;7395;BILL - To direct the Secretary of Health and Human Services to allow delivery of medical supplies by unmanned aerial systems, and for other purposes.;No cosponsors
Rep. Luetkemeyer, Blaine [R-MO-3];Republican;7394;"BILL - To prohibit the Federal financial regulators from requiring compliance with the accounting standards update of the Financial Accounting Standards Board related to current expected credit loss (""CECL""), to require the Securities and Exchange Commission to take certain impacts of a proposed accounting principle into consideration before accepting the principle, and for other purposes.";Rep. Budd, Ted [R-NC-13]*
Rep. Faso, John J. [R-NY-19];Republican;7393;BILL - Medicaid Quality Care Act;No cosponsors
Rep. Babin, Brian [R-TX-36];Republican;7392;BILL - TRACED Act;No cosponsors
Rep. Arrington, Jodey C. [R-TX-19];Republican;7391;BILL - Rural Hospital Freedom and Flexibility Act of 2018;No cosponsors
Rep. Jackson Lee, Sheila [D-TX-18];Democratic;7390;BILL - Violence Against Women Extension Act of 2018;Rep. Hoyer, Steny H. [D-MD-5] - Rep. Clyburn, James E. [D-SC-6]
```

When using a `csv.writer()` the file should always be opened with the `newline=''` parameter. This avoids getting double spaced rows in the CSV file.

I suggest searching for `[D` or `[R` in the text, as there will probably already be a `D` or `R` in the rest of the text.

Comment: I have also tried this code and it works perfectly. Thanks also for the general tip. 
I really appreciate.

Comment: @stancoantonio94, I just realised from your edit that you were trying to extract the bill number. I have updated the answer to show one possible way to do this.

Comment: I cannot explain with words how greatful I am

Comment: can I disturb with one last question? I also need data on cosponsor, namely the number of cosponsor for every bill and the party of the cosponsors and I dunno how to extract

Comment: You would need to get the cosponsor count, if non-zero get the link, reguest the sub page and parse that for the cosponsors. You also need to consider how you want to handle multiple cosponsors in your output.

Comment: Can we talk privately so I can explain myself better?

Comment: You would need more reputation to be able to use the stackoverflow chat system. Communication outside of this is discouraged.

Comment: I have taken the time to show you how to get the cosponsors by making additional subpage requests.